# Hibernate Tools in Eclipse: Change in column values does not reflecting in the query result

Tags: java, database, eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I am using Eclipse indigo and hibernate tools 3.3  for testing my hql queries.

I have configured hibernate tools correctly. But when I am querying to db after changing the values in a column, the old data is coming in result. When I closed the configuration and again connect, I am getting updated result.

Is hibernate tools caching the table values? if yes how to disable that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about auto-commit/ commit config ?

Comment: thank you. I have configured auto commit true in hibernate.cfg.xml file and it worked.